# Finding DLL References

Tags: windows, dll

I can't find an answer to a question I have for quite a bit of time, maybe it is too obvious that I am missing..

Well, here it is:

```
Where can I find a DLL Reference manual, with methods listing, etc?
```

Windows (Among others) has a lot of General-Purpose DLL's, and I can't find references for it.

Thank you.

Comment: That's backwards.  You start with the documentation, you'll find the DLL to go with it, often automatically without you doing anything to select it and unaware of it being used.

Comment: But if i HAVE to explicitly use a dll?

Comment: No, at most you use the import library of the DLL.  It doesn't even have to have the same name.  A COM type library would be another example, no correspondence at all.  The dependencies of the DLL that gets loaded at runtime are slurped into your process as well, not all of them are documented.